# looking to split out an excel row into 1 line per option

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I have an excel sheet where I have a record containing a travel request, but I need to process this out so I can see all the combinations I need to book.

The original record entry looks like this

```
ID  Family   Father Mother   Children      Destinations
KT1 Smith     John  Joan    John,Mary   London,New York
```

and I need the final result to look like this

```
ID  Family      Father  Mother      Children        Destinations
KT1 Smith       John    Joan         John              London
KT1 Smith       John    Joan         Mary              London    
KT1 Smith       John    Joan         John              New York
KT1 Smith       John    Joan         Mary              New York
```

(there may be multiple entries under any  of the Children and destinations , and possibly other fields which would be needed as well )
I am really unsure of how to do this and would love some advice

Comment: You multiply Destinations with Children which gives you the number of rows. Define an array of size 5 (one for the header) by 5. First, write the headers. Then, to group by Destinations (as in your example), you loop through its elements, then you loop through the Children elements at the same time writing the same data of the other columns. Try it, and then return with your attempt and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerQuery.

Google its usage and where to find it if you're not familiar, a quick search will produce a lot of results ...

https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/the-complete-guide-to-power-query/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-load-or-edit-a-query-in-excel-power-query-ca69e0f0-3db1-4493-900c-6279bef08df4

From there, you can transform your data.

[image: PQ1]

[image: Split]

[image: PQ Result]

That will achieve your outcome with little to no fuss.

Comment: „Throw your Data into a text/CSV File ….“ why? The Data is in Excel he wrote.

Comment: @Chris, small oversight, no need to get your knickers in a twist.